# How to retrieve the addresses of my accounts in Geth?

Tags: go-ethereum

I am using Geth v1.7 and have created two accounts to test. However, I forget them. How to retrieve the addresses of my accounts in Geth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use this command:

```
eth.accounts
```